# Problemas com Modelagem de tabela com duas Foreign Keys

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, modelo-relacional

Preciso finalizar uma modelagem de um Banco de dados e estou com um impasse.

De forma bem simplificada, tenho 3 tabelas como segue:

**PROMISSÓRIAS**

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `picinin`.`promissorias` (
  `id_promissoria` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `emissao` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `vencimento` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `numeracao` INT NOT NULL,
  `valor` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_promissoria`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

**CHEQUES**

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `picinin`.`cheques` (
  `id_cheque` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `banco` INT NULL,
  `agencia` INT NULL,
  `conta` INT NULL,
  `numero` INT NULL,
  `valor` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
  `emissao` DATETIME NULL,
  `vencimento` DATETIME NULL,
  `status` CHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT 'e',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_cheque`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

**MOVIMENTAÇÕES**

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `picinin`.`movimentacoes` (
  `id_movimentacao` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `valor` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `id_promissoria` INT NOT NULL,
  `id_cheque` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_movimentacao`),
  INDEX `fk_movimentacoes_promissorias1_idx` (`id_promissoria` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_movimentacoes_cheques1_idx` (`id_cheque` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_movimentacoes_promissorias1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_promissoria`)
    REFERENCES `picinin`.`promissorias` (`id_promissoria`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_movimentacoes_cheques1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_cheque`)
    REFERENCES `picinin`.`cheques` (`id_cheque`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Nessas tabelas são inseridos os pagamentos em aberto de um cliente. Se a venda for feita para pagamento em 10 notas promissórias, insiro 10 registros na tabela **PROMISSÓRIA**. Se cheques for escolhida como forma de pagamento, cadastramos os 10 cheques emitidos pelo cliente na tabela **CHEQUES**.

Na terceira tabela **MOVIMENTAÇÕES**, controlamos os pagamentos, sejam eles das promissórias ou dos cheques, mas estou tendo problemas para criar os relacionamentos das chaves para garantir a integridade, ou seja, somente será baixado um título na tabela **MOVIMENTAÇÕES** se existir um relacionamento na tabela **PROMISSÓRIA** ou na **CHEQUES**.

Visualmente a modelagem está da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sabemos que na prática isso não funciona, pois se eu for dar baixa de uma promissória, o sistema vai pedir a informação de um cheque e vice e versa.

Como resolvo isso?

Comment: Dê uma estudada em particionamento. Particione a entidade `movimentacoes` em movimentações por cheque e movimentações por promissória e faça o relacionamento apropriado de cada uma delas.

Comment: Você fala para criar uma tabela que guardará os pagamentos dos cheques e outra para guardar os pagamentos das promissórias?

Comment: Movimentacoes----<movimentacoes_cheques>-----cheques pois um cheque pode pagar uma ou mais promissorias , e uma promissoria pode ser paga por mais de um cheque. Mas não sei se entendi o problema.